# Writing modified Beautiful Soup tree to file, while maintaining original XML formatting

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup

We have an XML document that has a tag we wish to alter:

`...<version>1.0</version>...`

It's buried deep in the XML file, but we're successfully able to use Beautiful Soup to replace its contents with a command-line parameter.

The problem is that after modifying the tree, we need to write back to the file we read it from. *But*, we want to maintain the original formatting of the document. When I use:

```
fileForWriting = open(myXmlFile, 'w')
fileForWriting.write(soup.prettify())
```

The `prettify()` call breaks the formatting, and I end up with:

```
<version>
 1.0
</version>
```

Is there any way to maintain the original formatting of the XML document, while replacing that single tag text?

**Note:** Using simply:

`fileForWriting.write(str(soup))`

Keeps the text and tags on the same line, but eliminates the indents and extra newlines that had been human-added for readability. Close, but no cigar.

**By request, the entire script:**

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs

import sys

xmlFile = sys.argv[1:][0]
version = sys.argv[1:][1]

fileForReading = open(xmlFile, 'r')
xmlString = fileForReading.read()
fileForReading.close()

soup = bs(xmlString)

soup.findAll('version')[1].contents[0].replaceWith(version)

fileForWriting = open(xmlFile, 'w')
fileForWriting.write(str(soup))
fileForWriting.close()
```

The script is then run using:

`python myscript.py someFile.xml 1.2`

Comment: What code are you using to match and replace?

Comment: @bossylobster Added the code for match/replace.

Comment: I was hoping that the matches/tags would have an index, position or line number, but it seems `BeautifulSoup` was not meant for such things: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beautifulsoup/sy2skfowsso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And if you use `xml.elementtree`, the `tree.write(file)` method replaces the **CRLF** by **LF** only, which also creates issues when trying to import the XML file into i.e. **PyXB**.

The solution I found is to use **ElementTree** just to find what I have to replace. Then I do `source_XML = 'new value'.join(source_XML.split('what you need to replace))` Finally a `file.write(source_XML)`

it's not nice, but it solves the issue. However, I do not mind about the indentations, so on this I can't really say. I would only use `pprint.pprint()` whenever I need to print it.